# Send a form using javascript without knowing the name

Tags: javascript, html

To use the form submit javascript function you need to know the name of the form.

```
document.forms["myform"].submit();
```

or

```
document.myform.submit();
```

to submit

```
<form name="myform">...</form>
```

In my case i have a completely random name as form name. What I do know is that there is always only one form element present at the page. Any ideas to submit the form using javascript?

```
<form name="145f88f84584594">...</form>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`document.forms` holds all forms.

This should work: `document.forms[0].submit();`.

Answer (score 2):

```
document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0].submit();
```

or if you're using [jQuery](http://jquery.com):

```
$("form:first").submit();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:
    document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0].submit()

Answer (score 1):

You can also just do: 'document.forms[0].submit();'

ps. learning jQuery will be worth the time if you are dealig with dom elements.